# Getting EReferences of a EMF model instance in a ComboBox of a TableViewer

Tags: model, reference, jface, emf, tableviewer

I need to set and get values of `EReferences` of an EMF model instance, for which I use a self implemented UI. In it there is a table viewer, where I can set/get the values of certain data types, such as from primitive ones to `Strings` or `Enums`. To do that I have extended the `EditingSupport`, which the `TableColumns` are using by calling the `setEditingSupport()`-method.

For `Boolean` and `Enum` values I use `ComboBoxCellEditor` and for all other types the simple `TextCellEditor`. But they are all `EAttributes` and I am kind of lost when it comes to exploiting the `EReferences` of an EMF model. What I need to achieve is actually the same as what the Eclipse Properties View does. Using also a `ComboBoxCellEditor` for accessible elements that can be referenced by the `EReference` properties of a model, after other necessary models are reloaded as a model.

So, my question is whether it is possible to get this done, just like by the other `EStructuralFeatures` and in an `EditingSupport`? I couldn't find any materials directly regarding this issue. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!